# Django show ModelForm as html form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to do a very simple django webpage where a user fills 2 fields of a form with two numbers, submits them and gets a result at the third field. I am using ModelForms.

For the moment I am only interested in the first part, where the user navigates to the url and is prompted a page with the empty form. I do the following, but the page I see at my browser has no form, and only the submit button. I don't know if that's because the ModelForm I try to embed in the html code is still empty, but I tried to give it default values and it still didn't work.
Any help will be very appreciated! :)

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^calculator/', views.calculate)
)
```

models.py:

```
class Calc(models.Model):
    field1 = forms.CharField()
    field2 = forms.CharField()
    field3 = forms.CharField()   

class CalcForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Calc
```

views.py:

```
def calculate(request):
    c = CalcForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #do the math
        #return ...
    else:
        return render_to_response('home.html', {'calculator': c})
```

home.html:

```
<form action="/calculator/" method="post"> 
<table>
{{ calculator }}<!--I also tried .as_p, .as_ul...-->
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Have you posted actual code? Everything looks correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the following:

```
class Calc(models.Model):
    field1 = forms.CharField()
    field2 = forms.CharField()
    field3 = forms.CharField()
```

to

```
class Calc(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Did you ever `syncdb` with the above code? Because if you would've, it must have thrown an error. This makes me think if your db has the correct tables or not. Make sure you `syncdb` after the above change.

Also, you should always check if an instance exist, This will also help you troubleshoot that if the object was correctly passed or not:

```
{% if calculator %}
    <h3>Calculation Form</h3>
    <form action="/calculator/" method="post"> 
        <table>
            {{ calculator }}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: +1 for the first part, but -1 for the template change. There's no reason to check the existence of every variable you use.

Comment: yeah preferably not for all variables, but for major ones around which your template is created.

Comment: thanks a lot, it did the trick for me! when trying to sync my code I found the errors, and by using models.CharField(max_length=10) corrected it

Comment: I was now wondering how to access to the ModelForm fields from views.py.
I try `c.Field3 = c.Field1 + c.Field2` but I get an error telling me that 'CalcForm' object has no attribute 'Field1'...

Comment: In the views you can access the data once the form has been posted like `request.POST.get('field1')` if you want to manipulate the data you may also override form's `clean` or `__init__` method(s), depending on your requirement of when you want to do the manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Your model should use models.CharField, not forms.CharField.